# VideoView error, when I load video by url

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-videoview

```
 val uri = Uri.parse("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
                                videoView.setVideoURI(uri)
                                videoView.pause()
                                videoView.seekTo(1)
```

It's my code. Code very simple and it works and we can play and see video, but in logs I see

```
W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4
V/MediaHTTPService: MediaHTTPService(android.media.MediaHTTPService@806a87): Cookies: null
V/MediaHTTPService: makeHTTPConnection: CookieHandler (java.net.CookieManager@8633fd2) exists.
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incomplete:

```
private void playVideo() {
VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.playvideo);
 Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos- 
bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4")
videoview.setVideoURI(uri);
videoview.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
videoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

@Override
public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
finish();
return false;
}
});

videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
mp.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(new OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
@Override
public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int arg1,int arg2) {
progress.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
});
}
});

videoview.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
@Override
public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
finish();
}
});

videoview.requestFocus();
videoview.start();
}
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks for more complete code, but how it solves problem?